# python-pptx / Updating an existing Powerpoint chart without its excel sheet replacement

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have a powerpoint presentation with charts I want to update from python.

Right now I am using **python-pptx** library which is great but its ***chart.replace_data()*** the method is replacing the excel sheet with chart data in the chart.

Unfortunately, some of my charts have data labels calculated in separate cells (f.e I am using a normal bar chart but showing % value data labels with additional words in them, which are calculated alongside in excel).

Is there any alternative way to update chart data not affecting other cells of the excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported in `python-pptx` and is unlikely to be added unless a project team wants to sponsor it. It's a legitimate use-case, just not common enough that most folks would want it bad enough to apply project budget.

If you wanted to dig into it, I expect you'd want to create a fork. You would need an Excel library that can *read* Excel (the current `XlsxWriter` package `python-pptx` uses is "write-only"), so that would be a new dependency.

You'd probably want to start from about here in the code:
https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/pptx/parts/chart.py#L65

It would *not* be a trivial undertaking. There would be a lot to map in as far as where the existing data was and what to do if the shape of the data changed (more/fewer rows/cols).

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: @scanny - how can we seek paid support from python-pptx for a small coding task (using python-pptx)?